# How to load a page from where I left after refreshing the page?

Tags: php, ajax

I have used AJAX and PHP to develop a quiz project. The issue is when I refresh the page, the page content gets loaded from the start, i.e. the page starts from Question no. 1. Is there any property, method or attribute available in AJAX that I can use so that when I load the page, it loads where I left from (i.e. from Question no. 5 and not from Q1)?

Comment: Set a session variable for each ajax call, and load your questions from there if the site gets reloaded.

Comment: do you maintain submission in db for each user ?